# Mapserver - hide error messages

Tags: mapserver, apache

Using mapserver 7.0, is there a way to suppress the error messages sent to the user, such as :-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
  <!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException>
  msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named &#39;FOO&#39;.
  msPostGISLayerOpen(): Query error. Database connection failed. Check server logs for more details.Is the database running? Is it allowing connections? Does the specified user exist? Is the password valid? Is the database on the standard port?
 </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Running in the apache environment.

I have tried setting the ERROR and EMPTY urls in the WEB header but they do not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to build some filter in front of Apache by yourself because a standard WMS server must send exceptions and the default format is XML. WMS client can override it with the &EXCEPTIONS= parameter. Formats supported by MapServer are  XML, INIMAGE, and BLANK http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html. If you can control the WMS client you might get happy by making it to ask for BLANK exceptions.